# how to use Php Svn functions

Tags: php, svn

I want to see the svn log of a file.
I am having a path of my files --

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, 'Username
');
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, 'password');
svn_auth_set_parameter(PHP_SVN_AUTH_PARAM_IGNORE_SSL_VERIFY_ERRORS, true); // <--- Important for certificate issues! 
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_NON_INTERACTIVE,              true); 
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_NO_AUTH_CACHE,                true);


echo( svn_log('/var/www/ims/trunk/app/Controller/PapersController.php', 23) );
```

I am referring link  :-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-log.php

This code is not returning me anything ??
I am new in SVN functions in PHP.. Please guide me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the same from the command line does it return anything?

`svn log -r 23 /var/www/ims/trunk/app/Controller/PapersController.php`

I am assuming not, since that doesn't appear to be a log file. The svn_log function is for showing svn logs, but you appear to be trying to get output from a controller.